# Add sticky sidebar

Tags: javascript, sticky

I'm trying to use sticky sidebar with [theiaStickySidebar](https://github.com/WeCodePixels/theia-sticky-sidebar) from Github projects. As it described in above link, this should be an easy work. I use below HTML construction:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
 <div class="theiaStickySidebar">
 ...
 </div>
</aside>
```

This all these scripts need to work.

And also using `scripts` mentioned at Github page as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/theia-sticky-sidebar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.content, .sidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
      // Settings
      additionalMarginTop: 30
    });
  });
</script>
```

But this doesn't work currectly.

Have I done something wrong in this process?

Comment: There us a typo in your class name it should be `jQuery('.content, .ssidebar').theiaStickySidebar({...});`

Comment: @SaurabhSharma That was a mistake in here. It's not working anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just didn't delete extra class `.content`. For:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
 <div class="theiaStickySidebar">
 ...
 </div>
</aside>
```

Must use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/theia-sticky-sidebar.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.sidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
      // Settings
      additionalMarginTop: 30
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery selector seems wrong. Use `.ssidebar` or `theiaStickySidebar` depending on which one you want as the sidebar.

eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.content, .ssidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
      // Settings
      additionalMarginTop: 30
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I typed wrong here. It's not working, that is not the problem.